# Joining multiple tables with left join where an entry doesn't exist in one of the joined tables returns nothing

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables that have to be joined on more than a single field, and can't get it to work when table 3 has no data

T1

```
id primary key
user_id
mydata
```

T2

```
id primary key
user_id
entry_id
mydata
```

T3

```
id primary key
user_id
entry_id
mydata
```

T4

```
id primary key
user_id
entry_id
mydata
```

I want to return all of T1 where a search string matches any of the other 3 tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) as id FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON (T1.user_id = T2.user_id AND T2.entry_id = T1.id)
LEFT JOIN T3 ON (T1.user_id = T3.user_id AND T3.entry_id = T1.id)
LEFT JOIN T4 ON (T1.user_id = T4.user_id AND T4.entry_id = T1.id)
AND (T1.mydata LIKE :s OR T2.mydata LIKE :s OR T3.mydata LIKE :s OR T4.mydata LIKE :s)
```

The query works when all tables have entries, but when say T3 has no entries matching entry_id, nothing is returned.

What am I doing wrong, I can't seem to solve this... please help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by replacing AND with WHERE, so this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) as id FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON (T1.user_id = T2.user_id AND T2.entry_id = T1.id)
LEFT JOIN T3 ON (T1.user_id = T3.user_id AND T3.entry_id = T1.id)
LEFT JOIN T4 ON (T1.user_id = T4.user_id AND T4.entry_id = T1.id)
AND (T1.mydata LIKE :s OR T2.mydata LIKE :s OR T3.mydata LIKE :s OR T4.mydata LIKE :s)
```

becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) as id FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON (T1.user_id = T2.user_id AND T2.entry_id = T1.id)
LEFT JOIN T3 ON (T1.user_id = T3.user_id AND T3.entry_id = T1.id)
LEFT JOIN T4 ON (T1.user_id = T4.user_id AND T4.entry_id = T1.id)
WHERE (T1.mydata LIKE :s OR T2.mydata LIKE :s OR T3.mydata LIKE :s OR T4.mydata LIKE :s)
```

It seems the AND was causing the search criteria to become part of the last left join or something.